# Is it useless to use instance rendering on GL_POINTS?

Tags: c++, opengl

Currently I'm drawing GL_POINTS to a geometry shader rendering several million cubes and using a compute shader to calculate the velocities and positions for each cube. I was wondering if it's possible to use instanced rendering with geometry shader and compute shader but as I'm thinking about this it seems redundant as instancing a simple point would serve no purpose, or is it possible for even more efficiency?

Before all this, I was using instanced rendering on cubes on the CPU side + compute shader but only managed around 450k cubes nowhere close to even a million.

Comment: Using a geometry shader is already a performance trap in most cases, so avoiding that would be a good start.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, That's what I thought too.. but I'm easily reaching several million moving cubes using GL_POINTS -> Geometry Shader and using compute shader for velocity and acceleration calculations but well less than half a million for cube instancing + compute shader. I must be doing something wrong for the latter then...